# Generate and save to file a random string at compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to insert a random string into a program code or a resource at compile time and save that value externally for later reference.

For detail:

I had an idea that it might be possible to identify individual builds of programs if you could randomly generate a string at compile time and insert it into both the program and a storage file such that if you were to copy an individual build between two computers it would share the same string, but if you compiled it again the "new" version would have a different string.

It just a thought I had and couldn't find anything for c#, just things specific to c/c++ (like templates), though i could see this being useful in cases where you had a program used by a group of employees and could give each one a separate build so if there was a leak it could be easier to trace.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using git, how about adding the sha of the commit you're building?

Comment: Also, be *very* aware of the problem you're trying to solve here. If you want to prevent a dishonest employee from leaking your software you might consider other measures, or are you assuming that the employee is stupid enough not to figure out your hidden value? What stops that employee from grabbing a different user's copy and leaking that?

Comment: i wanted it to be able to generate a new string every time you publish the program via visual studio, and be able to use that string anywhere ie. string rando = #random

Comment: and the employee case was just an example, i was just thinking of how you could uniqely identify a build and the employee use case was an example.

Comment: Create a powershell script or something that does this and call it from the scripts you can call during build, check the project settings, there are some pre-build scripts you can set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your problem can be broken down into two parts

1. Storing and retrieving the random string in your code
2. Generating the random string at build-time

**Storing and retrieving the random string in your code**

This is the easy part. Because it will be auto-generated each time, you need to store it outside of your code. You can store it in a database table, a file, windows registry, on a remote server - it's up to you. That way, your code only needs a function to retrieve it from the location you saved it.

**Generating the random string at build-time**

I assume you are using visual studio, from the tag in the question. Here you can use the power of MSBuild. You would need to edit your CSPROJ file, to add the action to generate your random string during build and to push the generated string to the store location you chose above, inside an MSBuild targer.

The MSBuild targets you are interested in are either of these two:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"><!--Runs before build begins-->
</Target>
```

And

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild"><!--Runs after build completes-->
</Target>
```

You can run literally anything within these targets. For an example helloworld using C#, take a look at the following link [MSBuild Hello World](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2019#helloworld) on the Microsoft Documentation site.

Side note: I recommend the book Inside the Microsoft Build Engine - Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build by Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi and William Bartholomew.